# Why didn't Miguel follow the trail?

Tags: plot-explanation, sicario-day-of-the-soldado

In *Sicario Day of the Soldado (2018)*, Miguel gets down the bus and crosses the river with the Mexican 
migrants. As the Mexican migrants get into the truck, Miguel is met 
by one of them:

> Mexican: Follow the trail to the road. Your ride's waiting.

But Miguel approached the car, which had a mother and her baby. He asked 
the mother if she could drop him off at the Grocery store on Trenton. 
She agreed and drove him:

[image]

We can see Miguel and Mexican Migrants are going in different 
directions in this picture.

Why didn't Miguel follow the trail?

Answer (score 1):

Miguel's job was to escort the migrants across the border. Once he has done that, his job is over. The migrants continue their journey to reach a safe location in the US where they can attempt to integrate into society, but Miguel has no reason to go with them.

> Follow the trail to the road. Your ride's waiting.

He follows the trail to the road and indeed finds his ride, the woman in the van. He has done his job and can now go home.

Comment: Yup, the last sentence hits the nail:  he is following exactly those instructions. The ride waiting for him is indeed the woman, she even anticipates his surprise at finding her being his ride (I think she mentions something about money being worth it). The Mexicans in the truck are nothing to do with him once hes got them across.